# In sharepoint designer List workflow, how to check folder is added in document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

In SharePoint designer List workflow created on Document Library in Sharepoint Foundation 2013, how to check folder is added in the document library?

I need to skip workflow steps when any new folder is created or renamed. Currently, my workflow is working fine for when any files are added or modified.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a string workflow variable.
2. Now create a lookup for your folder and set the variable to the folder's title. Take a look here for some helpful information and usage guidelines when it comes to list folders.
3. The actions dependent of the existence of the folder have to be placed inside an if-statement
   E.g. the if-statement should be like "if [variable] not equals [folder name]" if you want the actions only to be run when the folder does not exist

Comment: but I dont know the foldername. User can anytime create any number of folders with any name